# Inflating all layouts from res-folder

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging

There are 100+ layouts in a resource folder on android, I can go through them one by one and look at the preview in android studio. They all utilise code like:

```
tools:text="text for preview"
tools:visibility="visible"
```

Is there a way to inflate all those one after another in a list/linear layout? And upgrade the tools:xyz attribute to be shown as the real android:xyz attribute in this view

Context&Purpose: To show them in the app under a debug menu dedicated specifically to show available layouts. This is to communicate with both other developers and people without android studio.

I want to avoid doing it manually as it needs to be maintained and that can end very badly for debug functionality such as this. (And that it is a lot of layouts does not help either of course)

After writing it down it feels unlikely, but maybe someone out there have a nice angle on this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of each layout, inflating a hundred of them at once could be quite taxing. You may run out of memory, or get a fair bit of jank. If you are OK with this, then I would say try using the include tag in your debug screen layout

A simple/naive implementation would be something like

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/A"/>
    <include layout="@layout/B"/>
    <include layout="@layout/C"/>
    <include layout="@layout/D"/>
    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

I probably wouldn't recommend doing this, but it might get the job done.

As far as the second part of your question, using tools values as actual values, I don't think there is a way to accomplish this. In fact the tools values are not even available during run time as they are [stripped out during the build process](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html).